# Laravel Intervention Image and Facebook images

Tags: facebook, image, laravel, intervention

I'm making a code that downloads original Facebook images from my Facebook site, crops them and saves both the original and the cropped image, by using Image::make( $url ).

The issue comes when the code is trying to get an image from a shared post.
URLS to images that I've uploaded looks something like this: "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/xxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxx"
Whereas urls to images from shared posts look like this: "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=blablabla".

Trying to run Image::make( $url ) on the external.xx.blabla link throws "Unable to init from given binary data."

The strangest thing about this is, if I take the same link that throws and error, paste it into my browser and view the image and then run the code again, well, then it crops and saves the image. I have no idea what's going on.

Do I really have to view all external images first before it works?

Answer (score 0):

make() accepts many sources, such as images urls, binary or base64 data. Since your second url ends with .php, I think it might be throwing the library off. Try something like this instead:

```
$img = Image::make(file_get_contents('https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=blablabla'));
```

Comment: After putting that in instead, it now returns "Image source not readable". However, I tried to catch the Intervention exception, at then just did a print_r($e) on it. Turns out I'm getting a "browser not supported" by facebook. So it could probably have something to do with useragent, though I'm not sure how to set the useragent when I request images through Image::make()

Answer (score 0):

User-Agent was the issue from Facebook it seems.

I changed

```
Image::make( $url );
```

to

```
Image::make( file_get_contents( $url ) )
```

and then I added

```
$options = array( 'http' => array( 'header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" ) );
$context = stream_context_create( $options );
$img = Image::make( file_get_contents( $attachments->media->image->src, false, $context ) );
$img = Image::make( file_get_contents( $url, false, $context ) )
```